# How do I remove the lens from the 'gear VR framework'?

Tags: virtual-reality, oculus, gear-vr

How do I remove the lens border from the 'gearvr framework'?

Or, how do I get the lens border values (width, height) in the 'gearvr framework'?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean removing the barrel distortion? That is, no black borders around the rendered views for each eye?

If you haven't already, please post at
https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/issues

There are a lot more Samsung developers working on GearVRf who can help you there